# How can I affordably retrieve data from Amazon Glacier?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a bit of an odd question. I stored several hundred gigabytes of disk image files (100+ GB each) on Amazon Glacier several years ago, shortly after Amazon Glacier launched. I'm not a web or app developer and just uploaded the files using SAGU (Simple Amazon Glacier Uploader). Now I'd like to retrieve my files without spending a fortune. When I first uploaded the files to Amazon I had no understanding of Glacier's download pricing structure. Twice I accidentally racked up huge bills, which Amazon very, very graciously forgave.

What should I do next? Is there a way to cheaply move the data into something designed for more flexible downloading and then download it from there? As I said before, I'm not an AWS developer; but I am comfortable using a command line if I'm told what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to define 'affordably'.  From the [Glacier FAQ site](https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/faqs/#dataretrievals)

> Q: How much do Standard retrievals cost?
>
> Standard retrievals are priced at a flat rate of $0.01 per GB and
>   $0.05 per 1,000 requests. For example, retrieving 500 archives that
>   are 1 GB each would cost 500GB x $0.01 + 500 x $0.05/1,000 = $5.025

and

> Q: How much do Bulk retrievals cost?
>
> Bulk retrievals are priced at a flat rate of just $0.0025 per GB and
>   $0.025 per request. For example, retrieving 500 archives that are 1 GB
>   each would cost 500GB x $0.0025 + 500 x $0.025/1,000 = $1.2625.

So, by my calcs, 1 TB will cost $10.05 using standard retrieval and <$2.53 using bulk to download. What sort of pricing are you looking for?